# I want to get out some codes out of the main function

Tags: c++

I want to get following parts out side the main function..I've written a coffee machine code for one of my my university assessment..I have written the whole code inside the main function.But now I want get that code part outside the main function..i mean those parts in a different function and call that function inside the main function.please help me.

```
enter code 


 int main() {
    softdrink drink[7];


strcpy(drink[0].name,"Espresso"); drink[0].itemprice=120;drink[0].country="Italy"; drink[0].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[1].name,"Iced coffee"); drink[1].itemprice=150;drink[1].country="France"; drink[1].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[2].name,"Long black"); drink[2].itemprice=80;drink[2].country="Australia"; drink[2].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[3].name,"Americano"); drink[3].itemprice=100;drink[3].country="America"; drink[3].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[4].name,"Latte"); drink[4].itemprice=200;drink[4].country="Italy"; drink[4].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[5].name,"Irish coffee"); drink[5].itemprice=130;drink[5].country="Ireland"; drink[5].quantity=20;
strcpy(drink[6].name,"Cappuccino"); drink[6].itemprice=180;drink[6].country="Italy"; drink[6].quantity=20;

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);


    int coffeetype = 1;

while(coffeetype != 8){
cout<<"\n 1) "<<drink[0].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[0].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[0].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[0].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 2) "<<drink[1].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[1].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[1].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[1].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 3) "<<drink[2].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[2].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[2].country<<"\t("<<drink[2].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 4) "<<drink[3].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[3].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[3].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[3].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 5) "<<drink[4].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[4].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[4].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[4].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 6) "<<drink[5].name<<"\t"<<drink[5].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[5].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[5].quantity<<") remaining";
cout<<"\n 7) "<<drink[6].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[6].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[6].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[6].quantity<<") remaining";

cout<<"\n 8) Leave the drink machine \n\n";
cout<<"\n Choose one:";
cin >> coffeetype;
```

Comment: it is very much readable to initialize *drink* when you define it rather than after as you do. Why do you not define the `operator<<` on *softdrink* or use a *for* loop to not repeat the code ?

Comment: Is my answer ok/understandable for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is arbitrary complicated and non readable for nothing, you can initialize *drink* when you declare it, and you can use a *for* loop to print each entry rather than to write all the time the same code, for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct softdrink {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;
};

int main() {
    softdrink drink[] = {
      { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
      { "Long black", 80, "Australia", 20 },
      { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
      { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Irish coffee", 130, "Ireland", 20 },
      { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
    };

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);

    int coffeetype = 1;

    while (coffeetype != 8) {
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)
        cout<< "\n " << i+1 << ") "<<drink[i].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[i].quantity<<") remaining";

      cout<<"\n " << i+1 << ") Leave the drink machine \n\n";
      cout<<"\n Choose one:";
      cin >> coffeetype;
    }
}
```

Of course you can also define the `operator<<` on *softdrink* and use it in *main*. If you add new elements in your array the *8* will not be the right value, to use a literal value is dangerous because you can miss to update it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct softdrink {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;
};

ostream & operator<<( ostream & os, const softdrink & sd)
{
  os << sd.name << "\t\t" << sd.itemprice << "\t\t" << sd.country << "\t\t(" << sd.quantity << ") remaining";
  return os;
}

int main() {
    softdrink drink[] = {
      { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
      { "Long black", 80, "Australia", 20 },
      { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
      { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Irish coffee", 130, "Ireland", 20 },
      { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
    };

    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(2);

    int coffeetype = 1;

    while (coffeetype != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0])) {
      int i;

      for (i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)
        cout << "\n " << i+1 << ") " <<  drink[i];

      cout<<"\n " << i+1 << ") Leave the drink machine \n\n";
      cout<<"\n Choose one:";
      cin >> coffeetype;
    }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall d.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

 1) Espresso        120     Italy       (20) remaining
 2) Iced coffee     150     France      (20) remaining
 3) Long black      80      Australia       (20) remaining
 4) Americano       100     America     (20) remaining
 5) Latte       200     Italy       (20) remaining
 6) Irish coffee        130     Ireland     (20) remaining
 7) Cappuccino      180     Italy       (20) remaining
 8) Leave the drink machine 


 Choose one:8
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

As you can see the use of *tab* is not the right way to have regular columns, so for instance modifying `operator<<` to have :

```
ostream & operator<<( ostream & os, const softdrink & sd)
{
  os << left << setw(5) << sd.name 
     << left << setw(10) << sd.itemprice 
     << left << setw(15) << sd.country 
     << '(' << sd.quantity << ") remaining";
  return os;
}
```

now the result is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

 1) Espresso       120       Italy          (20) remaining
 2) Iced coffee    150       France         (20) remaining
 3) Long black     80        Australia      (20) remaining
 4) Americano      100       America        (20) remaining
 5) Latte          200       Italy          (20) remaining
 6) Irish coffee   130       Ireland        (20) remaining
 7) Cappuccino     180       Italy          (20) remaining
 8) Leave the drink machine 


 Choose one:8
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

If to define the `operator<<` is to early for your level you can use a standard function :

```
void output(int i, const softdrink sd[])
{
  cout << "\n " << i+1 <<  ") "
     << left << setw(15) << sd[i].name 
     << left << setw(10) << sd[i].itemprice 
     << left << setw(15) << sd[i].country 
     << '(' << sd[i].quantity << ") remaining";
}
```

and in *main* :

```
for (i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)
  output(i, drink);
```

Note while *drink* is never modified you can also have it `const` :

```
const softdrink drink[] = {
...
```

I used an `int` for the index *i* but the right type is `size_t` for indexes, in that case also modify *output*

Also you are in C++, you have interesting classes to manage array, for instance `std::vector`, they have several advantages, you can get the number of elements, their size can be changed (even not needed here), they have *iterators* etc, so for instance *output* signature become

```
void output(size_t i, const vector<softdrink> & sd)
```

and *main* :

```
int main() {
    const vector<softdrink> drink = {
      { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
      { "Long black", 80, "Australia", 20 },
      { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
      { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Irish coffee", 130, "Ireland", 20 },
      { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
    };
    ...
    size_t coffeetype = 1;

    while (coffeetype != drink.size()) {
      size_t i;

      for (i = 0; i != drink.size(); ++i)
```

Note also your `while` is a `do while` because you initialize *coffeetype* to have the test of the `while` false :

```
size_t coffeetype;

do {
  ...
} while (coffeetype != drink.size());
```

Also if a non integer is given when you read *coffeetype* you will never read again and loop without ending, when you do an input always check it success, for instance if you decide to exit in case the input is invalid :

```
do {
  ...
  cout<<"\n Choose one:";
} while ((cin >> coffeetype) && (coffeetype != drink.size()));
```

Etc

As you can see a lot of things can be done to improve a code

Comment: `sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0])` no, pls don't do this. Use c++ standard containers like `std::vector` or `std::array`

Comment: Wow great explanation.Your answer made my day mate..Mmm one little question..I can get this drink[ ] part out side main function right?I mean put it in to a another function and call that function inside main fun.

Comment: also you should use range for

Comment: @bolov I can also use iterator, auto etc etc but I am afraid my answer is already too much for the OP :-)